# how to generate SQL from dbplyr without a database connection?

Tags: sql, r, database, hive, dbplyr

I currently have access to an Apache Hive database via the `beeline` CLI. We are still negotiating with IT to get `R` on the server. Until that time, I would like to (ab)use the `R` `dbplyr` package to generate SQL queries on another machine, copy them over, and run them as raw SQL. I have used `sql_render` in `dbplyr` in the past in instances where I had a valid database connection, but I do not know how to do this without a valid database connection. The ideal case, for me would be something like:

```
con <- dummy_connection('hive')   # this does not exist, I think
qry <- tbl(con,'mytable') %>%     # complex logic to build a query
  select(var1,var2) %>%
  filter(var1 > 0)   # etc...
sql_render(qry) %>%               # cat it to a file to be used on another machine.
  as.character() %>%
  cat()
```

Is there a way to make this 'dummy' connection? And can it be done in such a way that I can specify the variant of SQL?

Comment: why dont you try `sqldf` package for hands on `sql` query?

Comment: I am much more familiar with `dplyr` and `dbplyr`, and would rather not write SQL, which is the whole point here. Unless I have misunderstood you. Did you mean I should use `sqldf` to create a mockup database, like in sqlite?

Comment: This might help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/sql-translation.html

Answer (score 5):

You can generate an in-memory SQLite database using just R:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(RSQLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

data("diamonds")

dbWriteTable(con, "diamonds", diamonds)
```

With an in-memory SQL database & db connection, you should be able to (ab)use `dbplyr` connection to the database to get R to write SQL for you.

This is only SQLite, rather than Hive. But hopefully it is still an accelerator to go from R to SQLite to Hive (or your preferred SQL version).

Also see the following links:

- [SQLite vingette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html)
- [Bradley's demo](https://tbradley1013.github.io/2017/08/26/sql-management-in-r/) (source of above code)